# Term for the tree of all paths starting from a given vertex in a graph

Tags: terminology, trees, search-algorithms

What is the term for the tree (or a part of the tree) of all possible paths in a graph that start from a given (source) vertex?

This is the tree that is implicitly or explicitly constructed when doing shortest path search.  It appears, for example, in a [lecture on search](https://youtu.be/j1H3jAAGlEA?t=4m25s) of an [MIT Artificial Intelligence course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/index.htm), but I didn't understand if it has a name.

This is not a [*search tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) and not really a [*decision tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree).

Mathematically, it is a [covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph) tree, but is there a more appropriate term in the context of shortest path search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that Nils Nilsson in [*Principles of Artificial Intelligence* (1982)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4JwN5DTpcqkC&pg=PA27) calls it just a *search tree*, and *search tree* is also used in [*The Handbook of Artificial Intelligence* (1981)](https://archive.org/details/handbookofartific01barr/page/26) by Avron Barr and Edward Feigenbaum.  I've also found a sufficiently recent paper [*Predicting the size of IDA*ʼs search tree* (2013)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370213000039).

I will stick with *search tree*.

Answer (score 2):

It's the **self-avoiding walk tree** (SAW tree).

The trees seem to have been first considered by C.D. Godsil (*Matchings and Walks in Graphs*, *Journal of Graph Theory* 5(3):285–297, 1981; [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190050310); just before Lemma 2.4), though Godsil doesn't use the name.

<sub>(And, yes, "self-avoiding walk" is just a mighty-long way of saying "path".)</sub>

Comment: This does not look like a special term with a specific meaning. Of course a tree is a tree, and if it consists of self-avoiding walks, it is a tree of self-avoiding walks, or self-avoiding walk tree.  I've found out that *The Handbook of Artificial Intelligence* by Avron Barr and Edward Feigenbaum also uses *search tree* term, so i will probably stick with *search tree*.

Comment: Huh? You asked for a term for the trees you describe in the question. I gave you a specific term with that specific meaning. Perhaps it's not the term that is used in the community you're working with, but it is a specific answer to your question, and not some generic term that applies to anything at all.

Comment: Sorry, i meant rather *special term for the specific meaning*, but *self-avoiding walk tree* seems to be just a combination of *self-avoiding walk* and *tree*.  For example, google only finds 368 pages with "self-avoiding walk tree" in them (quoted)...

Comment: Probably I should have added that i was interested in this object in the context of path search in a graph.

Comment: By the way, Wikipedia currently defines [*self-avoiding walk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) chiefly for latices, and the term is not found in their [Glossary of graph theory terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms)...

Comment: I am not claiming that this is not an answer (i upvoted it, by the way), i am explaining why it does not satisfy me.

Comment: @Alexey OK. I'm satisfied that it doesn't satisfy you. :-)